# How to split and join flows in spring-batch to configure setup and teardown steps in a job

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-batch

I have reviewed [Spring-batch flow / split after a step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269091/spring-batch-flow-split-after-a-step) , and found that (a) the flagged solution doesn't parse because the split is unreachable, and (b) my usecase is different, so the intent of the answer is different.

I have also reviewed [How to configure mentioned use case using spring batch parallel step split flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933613/how-to-configure-mentioned-use-case-using-spring-batch-parallel-step-split-flow), but the solution there is to increase parallelization, not to split and join threads.

This seems to be a common enough usecase that it is should be an FAQ, but I have not seen a solution yet.

I have a parallelized spring-batch job, that I want to add setup and teardown steps to.  The setup and teatdown are single threaded, but the main body work is parallelized.

Diagrammed differently as events over time:

```
start        setup
               |
split       -------
            |     |
         some    other
         stuff   stuff
            |     |
join        -------
               |
finish      teardown
```

The spring-batch job XML I am starting from is:

```
<batch:job id="myJob">

    <batch:step id="step0001-setup">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager"
            start-limit="100" allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <batch:chunk reader="beforeJobScriptExecutor" writer="dummySinkWriter"
                commit-interval="1" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>


    <batch:split id="split1" task-executor="taskExecutor" next="step9999">

        <batch:flow>
            <batch:step id="step0003-one-thread"
                allow-start-if-complete="true">
                <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager"
                    start-limit="100">
                    <batch:chunk reader="myReader1" writer="myWriter1"
                        commit-interval="1" />
                </batch:tasklet>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:flow>

        <batch:flow>
            <batch:step id="step0002-another-thread">
                <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager"
                    start-limit="100">
                    <batch:chunk reader="myReader2" writer="myWriter2"
                        commit-interval="1" />
                </batch:tasklet>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:flow>

    </batch:split>


    <batch:step id="step9999">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager"
            start-limit="100" allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <batch:chunk reader="afterJobScriptExecutor" writer="dummySinkWriter"
                commit-interval="1" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was mostly outlined in this post:  [How to terminate Step within a Spring Batch Split Flow with a Decider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782008/how-to-terminate-step-within-a-spring-batch-split-flow-with-a-decider)

The final text of the spring-batch job is this:

```
<batch:job id="myJob">

    <batch:step id="step0001-setup">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager"
            start-limit="100" allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <batch:chunk reader="beforeJobScriptExecutor" writer="dummySinkWriter"
                commit-interval="1" />
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:end on="FAILED" />
        <batch:next on="*" to="split1" />
    </batch:step>


    <batch:split id="split1" task-executor="taskExecutor" next="step9999">

        <batch:flow>
            <batch:step id="step0003-one-thread"
                allow-start-if-complete="true">
                <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager"
                    start-limit="100">
                    <batch:chunk reader="myReader1" writer="myWriter1"
                        commit-interval="1" />
                </batch:tasklet>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:flow>

        <batch:flow>
            <batch:step id="step0002-another-thread">
                <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager"
                    start-limit="100">
                    <batch:chunk reader="myReader2" writer="myWriter2"
                        commit-interval="1" />
                </batch:tasklet>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:flow>

    </batch:split>


    <batch:step id="step9999">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager"
            start-limit="100" allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <batch:chunk reader="afterJobScriptExecutor" writer="dummySinkWriter"
                commit-interval="1" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```